# Is my SQL transaction taking too long?

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions

There is something that worries me about my application. I have a SQL query that does a bunch of inserts into the database across various tables. I timed how long it takes to complete the process, it takes about 1.5 seconds. At this point I'm not even done developing the query, I still have more inserts to program into this. So I fully expect this to process to take even longer, perhaps up to 3 seconds.

Now, it is important that all of this data be consistent and finish either completely, or not at all. So What I'm wondering about is, is it OK for a transaction to take that long. Doesn't it lock up the table, so selects, inserts, updates, etc... cannot be run until the transaction is finished? My concern is if this query is being run frequently it could lock up the entire application so that certain parts of it become either incredibly slow, or unusable. With a low user base, I doubt this would be an issue, but if my application should gain some traction, this query could potentially be a lot.

Should I be concerned about this or am I missing something where the database won't act how I am thinking. I'm using a SQL Server 2014 database.

To note, I timed this by using the StopWatch C# object immediately before the transaction starts, and stop it right after the changes are committed. So it's about as accurate as can be.

Answer (score 1):

You're right to be concerned about this, as a transaction will lock the rows it's written until the transaction commits, which can certainly cause problems such as deadlocks, and temporary blocking which will slow the system response. But there are various factors that determine the potential impact.
For example, you probably largely don't need to worry if your users are only updating and querying their own data, and your tables have indexing to support both read and write query criteria. That way each user's row locking will largely not affect the other users--depending on how you write your code of course.
If your users share data, and you want to be able to support efficient searching across multiple user's data even with multiple concurrent updates for example, then you may need to do more.

Some general concepts:
-- Ensure your transactions write to tables in the same order
-- Keep your transactions as short as possible by preparing the data to be written as much as possible before starting the transaction.
-- If this is a new system (and even if not new), definitely consider enabling Snapshot Isolation and/or Read Committed Snapshot Isolation on the database. SI will (when explicitly set on the session) allow your read queries not to be blocked by concurrent writes. RCSI will allow all your read queries *by default* not to be blocked by concurrent writes. But read this to understand both the benefits and gotchas of both isolation levels: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/

Answer (score 0):

I think its depend on your code, how you used loop effectively, select query and the other statement.